# My c# console application won't allow my variable with a Console.ReadLine() to recieve user input and instead counts from 1 upwards

Tags: c#, visual-studio

i've been going crazy with this, would really appreciate getting to know what's wrong with my code.

So the idea of the program is to simply recieve 5 different numeric values and then display all of those. everything seems to be working fine, except that my variable called

> valor

won't ask for input and it uses the number 1 and goes up from there, essentialy the program executes itself to 1, 2, 3, 4 without requesting the input. here's the code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var arrayNumeros = new double[5]; // pilas capaz es cinco en vez de 4
    Console.WriteLine("5 numerings diferentings xfa");
        
    for (var count = 0; count > 5; count++)
    {
        var valor = Console.ReadLine();
        var valorDouble = Convert.ToDouble(valor);
        var valoresPreviosTipeados = new List<double> { };
        valoresPreviosTipeados.Add(valorDouble);

        while (valoresPreviosTipeados.Contains(valorDouble))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("numeros diferents ooe");
            valor = Console.ReadLine();
            valorDouble = Convert.ToDouble(valor);
            continue;
        }

        arrayNumeros[count] = valorDouble;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("los numeros son ");

    for (double count = 0; count < 5; count++ )
    {
        if (count == 4) // pilas capaz es cinco en vez de 4
        {
            Console.Write("y " + count + ".");
            break;
        }
            
        Console.Write(count + ", ");T
     }
}
```

Comment: continue is the culprit in your code, remove it

Comment: `for (var count = 0; count > 5; count++)` ?… count is zero (0) which is NOT greater than 5. The loop will never get entered… I bet you want `count < 5`

Comment: Have tried carefully debugging it? Put a breakpoint at the top of your code and single step through each statement, looking at the values of the variables as you do

Comment: Share the code which can reproduce the scenario you described. Your first for loop is having `count >5` so does not entere in loop.

Comment: Side note: `var valor = Console.ReadLine(); var valorDouble = Convert.ToDouble(valor);` That's an exception waiting to happen... Never trust user input. Use `double.TryParse` instead. You might also do that in a loop and let the user know they've entered an invalid value and ask for the value again... Or you can use something like [ExtendedConsole](https://peled-zohar.github.io/ExtendedConsole/) which is an open source project that is designed (by yours truly) to help with .net console applications.